# Laravel 6.x - undefined function in config file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

My project contains a `projectInfo.yaml` file with something like:

```
. . .
softwareVersion: 1.0.0-dev
platforms:
  - windows
  - mac
  - linux
. . .
```

I'd like to get `softwareVersion` value and write it into an environment variable.

To do that, in the file `config/app.php`, I've added the line:

```
<?php

return [
    . . .
    'version' => trim(yaml_parse_file(base_path().'/projectInfo.yaml')['softwareVersion']),
    . . .
];
```

It works, and I can get this value by calling `config('app.version')`.

The problem appears when I run `php artisan`, the output returns:

```
$ php artisan
```

> In app.php line 4:
>   Call to undefined function yaml_parse_file()

Where is the error?

Comment: Maybe try a different command line (like homestead).  You may not have the right php build.

Comment: Yaml is a separate PECL extension that you need to install, apparently, according to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.yaml-parse-file.php

Comment: Yes! I installed It. I works out of the `php artisan` command.

Comment: Make sure it's enabled in both the CLI php.ini and FPM php.ini

Comment: Hi All. @aynber show me the correct way. I forgot to enable the yaml for CLI.